# How can I copy files to a network share using a file list stored in a SQL table?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table contains all destination IP Address of remote servers.
And would like to which is best way to copy files from local machine to all remote servers that inside SQL table.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: it is best to do it outstide of SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All DOS commands can be executed in T-SQL using an extended stored procedure,`xp_cmdshell`. However it is **strongly** recommended not to use the `xp_cmdShell` as it leads to vulnerable attacks. Instead this can be implemented using the **SSIS**.

To answer your question, i am giving a dumb example which can be extended further by having a cursor or any other loop statement to serve your need,

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdShell 'Copy C:\LuckyOld\*.*  C:\LuckyNew\'
```

Comment: @TanTran: Glad to suggest. SSIS gives more flexibility and maintainability. Feel free to drop a message for further assistance.

Comment: @TanTran Do a UP vote. So that others also can make use of this info.